# Lambda local variable default value fails to use the closured local variable

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

Consider the following piece of code:

```
x = 1
λ = ->(x = x) { puts "[#{x}]"; x = 2; puts "[#{x}]" }
```

I would expect that *the value of the topmost level local variable `x`* will be used as a default value for the lambda’s local variable `x`. That said, the code above should be more or less equivalent to:

```
λ = ->(x = 1) { puts "[#{x}]"; x = 2; puts "[#{x}]" }
```

Unfortunately, that is not the case: `(x = x)` is not treated that way and lambda’s local `x` is being initially set to `nil`:

```
λ.()
#⇒ []
#  [2]
```

Why the RHO in `(x = x)` is not taken from the outermost `binding`?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you needed this in application you would do `-> (x = nil) { x = x || default; ... }` where `default` is the out-of-block, in-scope local variable that you wish to use as the default.

Comment: @coreyward I did not ask how to overcome this, `->(x = default) { ... }` is sufficiently enough. I asked about why RHO is not treated as it should be.

Comment: Griping that the behavior is “not treated as it should be” is not within the scope of Stack Overflow, which aims to assist with actual, non-hypothetical programing questions. This is expected behavior in Ruby, per the language creator.

Comment: @coreyward This is an actual, non-hypotetical problem. If you don’t understand it, it does not mean the problem does not exist. RHO in no one language behaves this way. The answer “`x = x` code takes precedence over common sense and is always resolved to `x = nil`, despite scoping” would be fine (though a bit frustrating.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
λ = ->(x = x) {…}
```

In above code `x` argument identifier overshadows current scope local variable of the same name, so default value already refers to this argument and not original `x`.

For default value you may use distinct local variable name, instance variable or if insist, get outer `x` through `Binding#local_variable_get`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Are you serious ? What nonsense are you talking about ? In Ruby 2.2 or newer you would even get warning `circular argument reference - x`. See [bugreport #10314](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10314) for details. It confirms what I've written.

Comment: 1. It is called “scope” and has nothing to do with “namespaces,” that usually refers the `Module` nesting. 2. Methods do introduce new scope, while `proc`s/`lambda`s **do not**; try: `x = 1; λ = ->(y = x) { puts local_variables }`. 3. In `y = x`, `x` is a RHO and must be resolved by the outermost scope. 4. I have no idea, why Matz thinks this behaviour is OK, but fine, MINSWAN.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is word nitpicking. The main point persists - argument definition overshadows local variables. I'd fix the answer with correct terms.

Comment: Also, the bug you linked has a little relation to my question: this was breaking change in methods; lambdas behave this way always. That say, in `2.1.10`, `def x; 1; end; def foo(x = x); puts x; end; foo` successfully prints `1`, while my example still fails.

Comment: If `Binding#local_variable_get` would work, `x = x` would indeed work as well. There are apparently three different bindings, one in outer scope, one inside block parameters definitions (sic!) and one inside block itself.

Comment: It is related, as it concerns name clash between argument name and existing local variable name. In updated example, you dodge with method definition instead of local variable, as in OP. If original example kept, you would receive undefined local variable x error. Btw. Ruby 2.1 is close to EOL.

Comment: I think you still dont understand. `Binding#local_variable_get` would work, because it works around name conflict. `x = 1; orig = binding; foo = -> (x = orig.local_variable_get(:x)) {p x }; foo.call  # 1` .

Comment: Ah, being explicitly declared in the outermost scope it indeed would work.